# Raspberry Pi DesktopでRedshiftというブルーライトカットソフトが有効にならない

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

**現象**
64bit版Raspberry Pi DesktopでRedshiftというブルーライトカットソフトを有効にしたのですが、ブルーライトをカットすることができません。

**期待値**
64bit版Raspberry Pi DesktopでRedshiftを使ってブルーライトをカットしたい。

**再現手順**
`$ sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk`を実行する。

`/home/pi/.config/redshift.conf`に下記の設定を書き込む。

```
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=5800
temp-night=1800

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night since version 1.8.
brightness-day=0.9
brightness-night=0.7
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel individually)
gamma=0.9

;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=geoclue2

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; e.g. 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
lat=130
lon=32

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the second screen.
[randr]
screen=0
crtc=0
```

最後に、RedshiftをGUIから起動する。

**今まで調べたこと・試したこと**
[Stack Exchangeの「Is there any way to get redshift to work?」という質問](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13905/is-there-any-way-to-get-redshift-to-work)
と
[Raspberry Piの動画や３Dなどのグラフィック表示をスムーズにするOpenGLとGPUメモリ](https://www.fabshop.jp/opengl_gpumemory/)
を参考に、OpenGLを有効化しました。

`raspi-conf`で設定をしたが、私の環境(64bit版Raspberry Pi Desktop)では、`GL (Full KMS)`という選択肢は存在しなかったため、`GL (Fake KMS)`を選択してOpenGLを有効化しました。

Comment: GUI のツールのようですが、起動自体はできているのですか？

Comment: @cubick はい、起動自体はできています。